# How do I use the formula $|\langle \psi | \psi \rangle|^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Suppose I have a state:

$$
| \psi \rangle = \pmatrix{ a_1+ib_1\\a_2+ib_2}
$$

I wish to calculate the probability of observing the state $\psi_1$.

---

1. 

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_1 | \psi \rangle &= \pmatrix{a_1-ib_1 & 0 } \pmatrix{a_1+ib_1\\a_2+ib_2}\\
&=a_1^2+a_1ib_1-ib_1a_1+b_1^2\\
&=a_1^2+b_1^2
\end{align}
$$

2.

$$
\begin{align}
|\langle \psi_1|\psi \rangle|=\sqrt{(a_1^2+b_1^2)(a_1^2+b_1^2)}
\end{align}
$$

3.

$$
|\langle \psi_1|\psi \rangle|^2=(a_1^2+b_1^2)^2
$$

So the probabilities are the square of the complex norm? The components of the complex numbers are of degrees four?

---

edit:

or maybe I am doing step 1 wrong...? Should it be:

1.

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \psi_1 | \psi \rangle &= \pmatrix{1 & 0 } \pmatrix{a_1+ib_1\\a_2+ib_2}\\
&=a_1+ib_1
\end{align}
$$

Then I get

$$
|\langle \psi_1 | \psi \rangle|^2=a^2+b^2
$$

?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking about. Yes, to calculate the probability of measuring state $|\phi\rangle$ when the system is in state $|\psi\rangle$, you take the inner product of the two vectors, take the absolute value of that and square it. However $|\phi\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle$ can really be any two normalized vectors, so it's not very useful to write down the “most general” formula for that.

Comment: The only difference between your edits is the way you define $\psi_1$.

Comment: closely related to the closed question  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645306/quantum-probabilities-of-a-projection-does-it-require-two-different-definition by the same OP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The second method is correct. This is because $(a_1+ib_1\ 0)^T$ is not the matrix of the wavefunction $\psi_1$. Rather-

$$\psi=(a_1+ib_1)\psi_1+(a_2+ib_2)\psi_2$$

In matrix form when you wrote the expression for $\psi$, you already assumed that $\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}$ is the basis. Thus the matrix you have written for $\psi$ above is the coordinatisation of $\psi$ with respect to the given basis.

This is why the matrix for $\psi_1$ is $(1\ 0)^T$.

Edit: I assumed that the OP has taken $\{\psi_1,\psi_2\}$ to be an ordered basis, and he acknowledges this in the comments.

Comment: How one marks their basis is completely arbitrary, $\psi_1$ can as well be another state.

Comment: Given that in most of these problems we want to observe probabilities of finding quantum particles in eigenstates only, I assumed OP took, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ as the only possible measurement results, and that these are eigenstates of some operator. I guess it makes sense then. In other words, not everything needs to be written in the question.

Comment: You assumed correctly. Thanks for clearing this up for me.